# How to show information by selecting a date from the list

Tags: html, angular, angular-template

There are  two such models:

note.model.ts:

```
export class Note{
    constructor(
        public note_id?:number,
        public note_text?: string,
        public years?: number
    ) { }
}
```

year.model.ts:

```
export class Year{
    constructor(
        public years?:number
    ) { }
}
```

How can I choose the date (the Year model) from the list to display only the information in the table that matches the date with the selected from select?

```
<select>
  <option type="number"  *ngFor="let year of years">
    {{ year.years }}
  </option>
</select>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Note</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let note of notes">
                <td>{{note.note_text}}</td>
                <td>{{note.years}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML you can add a click event:

```
<select>
  <option type="number" *ngFor="let year of years" (click)="onYearSelection(year.years)">
    {{ year.years }}
  </option>
</select>
```

and iterate through a filtered notes list:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Note</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let note of filteredNotes">
                <td>{{note.note_text}}</td>
                <td>{{note.years}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And in your ts file you can write code to filter the notes list on the basis of the selected year.

```
filteredNotes = [];

onYearSelection(year){
    this.filteredNotes = []
    this.filteredNotes = this.notes.filter(note => note.years == year);
}
```